# Android Java How to properly remove int from list?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

Currently I am trying to write a code that will create a list from various points coordinates and then remove 3 smallest ints from the list. When I run the app, it crashes. I figured out that i happens in remove part. I have looked into other similar threads, but the solution are similar to what I have. Here's the code I have:

```
    List<Integer> XPoint = Arrays.asList(A.x, B.x, C.x, D.x, E.x, F.x, G.x, K.x);
    List<Integer> XPLeft = Arrays.asList();
    int XPLeftTimes = 0;

    //Find 3 min X values(left)
    while(XPLeftTimes != 2){
    int Left = Collections.min(XPoint);
    XPoint.remove(Left); <-App crashes here
    XPLeft.add(Left);
    XPLeftTimes++;
    }
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: asList Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. The size of the List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays.asList() returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

try

```
List<Integer> xPoint = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(A.x, B.x, C.x, D.x, E.x, F.x, G.x, K.x));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `XPoint.remove(left);` it is not removing that part it is removing whatever value is stored at the index(which is equal to left) that's why it is crashing If you want to remove that number try this

```
XPoint.remove(new Integer(left));
```

Comment: Thanks. I used Integer.valueOf(Left) though.

Comment: Welcome , need more help just say

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList() returns fixed size array which cannot be modified.
if you want to modify it, you have to create a new modifiable Arraylist by copying its contents as follows:

```
List XPoint = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(A.x, B.x, C.x, D.x, E.x, F.x, G.x, K.x));
```

List XPLeft = new ArrayList();

This should work.